# Get row index for queried element in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to get the position of an item in my vector, turns out to be difficult:

My data table holds 5 columns

```
                   ts Q_m3s Baseflow_r1 Baseflow_r2 leer_1 year
 1: 1965-01-01 00:00:00   156         156         150      0   65
 2: 1965-01-01 01:00:00   155         155         150      0   65
 3: 1965-01-01 02:00:00   154         154         150      0   65
 4: 1965-01-01 03:00:00   154         154         150      0   65
 5: 1965-01-01 04:00:00   153         153         150      0   65
 6: 1965-01-01 05:00:00   152         152         150      0   65
```

The first column ts is converted to a POSIXct element

```
dt <- data.table(data) # convert to data table 
dt[,ts:=as.POSIXct(ts, format="%m%d%Y %H:%M")] # convert to POSIXct
# get year
dt[, ':='(year=as.POSIXlt(ts)$year)]
```

I now want to get the POSITION of the maximum value in a given year.

The expression `max(dt$Q_m3s[dt[,year==105]])` yields the maximum per selected year, but I have no idea how to get the position, i.e. the row index.

Any help appreciated!
Best 
Jochen

Answer (score 3):

Try below. `.I` is `data.table` specific internal variable that you can use in `j` argument of data.table extraction.

```
require(data.table)

set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(year = rep(1:5, each = 3), var = sample(1:15))
DT
##     year var
##  1:    1   5
##  2:    1  12
##  3:    1   6
##  4:    2  11
##  5:    2  14
##  6:    2   1
##  7:    3  15
##  8:    3   8
##  9:    3   4
## 10:    4   3
## 11:    4   9
## 12:    4   2
## 13:    5  13
## 14:    5   7
## 15:    5  10


DT[, .I[which.max(var)], by=year]
##    year V1
## 1:    1  2
## 2:    2  5
## 3:    3  7
## 4:    4 11
## 5:    5 13
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just an individual year (rather than one for each year), then

```
which(dt$year==105)[which.max(df$Q_m3s[dt$year==105])]
```

should work - the expression in the bracket finds the index, within the rows corresponding to year==105, of the maximal value of q_m3s, and then we find the corresponding index in the whole dataset.

If you're looking at finding the maximal value for each year, then an expression along the lines of

```
.I[which.max(df$Q_m3s)], by=year
```

will give you the index in the whole dataset of each year's maxmimal Q_m3s - the `.I` being an internal variable that stores the indices of each groups rows.